# is modelmapper mapping proses very slow

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, modelmapper

Iam using modalmapper in spring boot restfull service (iam newbee).  i tried to get list files from my webservice, it works but the response time is very slow..
here's my entity users & files which has one to many relation:

**USERS ENTITY (not include getter & setter just to make it shorter):**

```
@Entity(name = "users")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1940389980816353573L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 150, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String encryptedPassword;

    
    private String emailVerificationToken;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private boolean emailVerificationStatus = false;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AddressEntity> addresses;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<NuFileEntity> files;

}
```

**Files ENTITY (not include getter & setter just to make it shorter):**

```
@Entity(name = "files")
public class NuFileEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4960899439133364162L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String fileId;

    @Column(length = 55, nullable = false)
    private String fileName;

    @Column(length = 15, nullable = false)
    private String fileType;

    @Lob
    private byte[] fileContent;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Timestamp fileUploadTimestamp;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Timestamp lastUpdatedTimestamp;
    
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Timestamp fileMateraidTimestamp;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "integer default 0")
    private int materaiPage;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "integer default 0")
    private double materaiX;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "integer default 0")
    private double materaiY;
    
    @Column(columnDefinition = "integer default 0")
    private boolean meteraid;
    
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = true)
    private String listEmailOfSignees;
    
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = true)
    private String listWhoSigned;
    
    @Column(length = 99, nullable = true)
    private String fileIsNowViewByUser;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "users_id")
    private UserEntity userDetails;

}
```

**this is my file.dto:**

```
public class NuFileDTO {
    private long id;
    private String fileId;
    private String fileName;
    private String fileType;
    private byte[] fileContent;
    private Timestamp fileUploadTimestamp;
    private Timestamp lastUpdatedTimestamp;
    private Timestamp fileMateraidTimestamp;
    private int materaiPage;
    private double materaiX;
    private double materaiY;
    private boolean meteraid;
    private String listEmailOfSignees;
    private String listWhoSigned;
    private String fileIsNowViewByUser;
    private UserDto userDetails;
```

**then this is my serviceImplementation:**

```
@Override
public List<NuFileDTO> getListInfoUserFiles(String userId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<NuFileDTO> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    UserEntity userEntity = userRepo.findByUserId(userId);
    if (userEntity == null)
        return returnValue;
    System.out.println("findByUserId done");
    Iterable<NuFileEntity> files = fileRepo.findAllByUserDetails(userEntity);
    System.out.println("findListInfoUserFiles done");
    int i=0;
    for (NuFileEntity fileEntity : files) {
        System.out.println("enter iteration "+i);
        NuFileDTO tmp = modelMapper.map(fileEntity, NuFileDTO.class);
        System.out.println("extracted "+i);
        System.out.println("adding start "+i);
        //returnValue.add(modelMapper.map(fileEntity, NuFileDTO.class));
        returnValue.add(tmp);
        System.out.println("iteration "+i+++" done");
    }
    System.out.println("returnValue="+returnValue.size());
    return returnValue;
}
```

and this is response that i get from postman:
[image]

So, **it takes 30s just to retrieve 4 tiny file and all resides in local machine (STS, MYSQL)**.....where did i do wrong? iam prety sure modelmapper wont be this slow.....

Thanks..

Okay i've edited my mapping process into 3 different approach;

1. fully using modelmapper (nested class)
2. one one class is mapped using model mapper
3. manually mapp
   bellow is the mappring code

[image]

and here are the result:
[image]

So there it is, is this normal? or modalmapper are only meant to use for development only?

Comment: Add  timestamp to your `System.out.println` statements, like System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + "enter iteration "+i )), and paste the outputs,then find the slow statements.

Comment: i did, the slow staement is @ NuFileDTO tmp = modelMapper.map(fileEntity, NuFileDTO.class);

Comment: @tianwei i've edited my post just like u suggest, and as the result without using model mapper the prosess is done instanly.

Comment: Fields `addresses` and `files` in `Entity` are `onetomany`,you should test if getting these values take long time(by using `fileEntity.getUserDetails().getAddresses()` and `fileEntity.getUserDetails().getFiles()`)